# AWS EKS throw error: exec /usr/local/bin/yarn: exec format error

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, ubuntu, amazon-eks

I am building a nodejs app with docker, I am building on an EC2 instance `(ubuntu/arm64)  ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-arm64-server-20211129` , and deploy it to AWS EKS, the node I am using is `ubuntu-eks/k8s_1.22/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20220630`, however the pod goes into `CrashLoopBackOff` status, and gives me the following error:

`exec /usr/local/bin/yarn: exec format error`

here is how my Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 node:16-alpine as builder

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python3

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --production

FROM --platform=linux/arm64 node:16-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node ./ .
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 4004

ENTRYPOINT ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Are you building this on an M1 Mac, or some other non-Intel system?  Does it help things to make the final stage also be `FROM --platform=linux/amd64`?

Comment: I updated my question, i am building on an EC2 instance (ubuntu/arm64)

Answer (score 4):

The reason turned out to be the image was built one `linux/arm64`, but was running on `linux/amd64`, after I changed my node to be `linux/arm64`, it starts to run.

Answer (score 1):

As from docker API version `1.40`, you can specify the platform upon which your image needs to be built by using the `--platform` option.

```bash
docker build . --platform=linux/amd64
```